# Use of 230VAC overcurrent protection for 24VDC circuits

Tags: ac, dc, protection, circuit-protection

Is it right to use 230VAC overcurrent protection for 24VDC circuits? Why? Why not?
For example: http://www.tme.eu/en/details/a9f05120/circuit-breakers/schneider-electric/

I saw some machines which have this kind of overcurrent protection in 24VDC circuits. I always used dedicated 24VDC protections like https://www.phoenixcontact.com/us/products/3036547 with approperiate fuse.

Comment: Your question(s) are too broad to provide an answer, and as it is runs the risk of being rejected or put on hold. Please re-write your question so actual questions end with a '?', and be specific. Your request to cover all the bases by 'physics and regulations' is not practical to do.

Comment: While I cannot effectively read/translate the datasheet at the tme.edu link, be aware that the iC60N series of circuit breakers has devices with ratings for AC use, DC use, or both DC and AC use. You would need to verify the specifications of the exact model you are using or have seen used.

Comment: No, you can't use AC circuit breakers in a DC circuit. You need a DC circuit breaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it right to use 230VAC overcurrent protection for 24VDC circuits?

Circuit breakers work by current, not voltage. The voltage rating is the maximum voltage the breaker can safely and dependably interrupt if a short occurs downstream.
 *Normally using a AC breaker in a DC circuit is not a good idea*, as the AC breaker is expecting a zero-crossing point at least 100 to 120 times per second. DC current is non-stop and runs the risk of the breaker contacts welding/arc welding together and things going "BOOM". Those who did the 230vac breaker installation are counting on the low voltage DC to not have enough energy to destroy the breaker if a short occurs. If it passed inspection, there must be guidelines I am not aware of and do not have access to.
Other issues would be physical space, contact type (to the breaker panel), and if you want a built-in fuse. It is not wrong to use a breaker at a lower voltage than its maximum rating, but it must fit properly to the panel used. Fuses would not fit in the same panel.
If you have the option, for your own 24vdc designs I would use the fused version (2nd link) with a built-in 24vdc LED. Using a 230vac breaker seems like a waste of money, even if some test labs use them for 24vdc protection, at their own risk. 
You paying for your own parts is much different than a company that can throw thousands of dollars or euros into a simple 24vdc power distribution panel. Play it safe and use DC breakers and fuses on DC circuits.

Comment: Voltage **does** matter when comparing DC and AC. AC breakers are designed knowing that there are 120 or 100 zero-crossings per second to limit arc energy. It is inappropriate, possibly even unsafe, to use an AC-only breaker in a DC application.

Comment: @user2943160. Just for a sense of balance and as a warning of potential disaster, I added a paragraph defining the penalty that could occur when using AC breakers in a DC circuit. If the OP uses a DC fuse bank as planned, there should be no fault issues.

Comment: Vote changed. Also note that the referenced breaker has a fairly complex array of options in that model line, as I commented on the question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "Is it right" you would need to know what trip curve the overcurrent protection needs to respond within.  A 20 amp circuit breaker that sees 21 amps will respond in a different time period on the curve versus seeing 500 Amps.

A major cost in circuit breaker design and liability is listed on the Schnieder website as "Short Circuit Breaking capacity" and is rated at 6 KA.  Circuit Breaker size and cost go up as these ratings go up to 5 ka versus 20 ka.  Think of this as the maximum current rating that a circuit breaker can safely clear or open under.  Install a 5 ka device in a circuit that can see 20 ka and if it sees a 20 ka fault it will most likely explode or weld shut.

Based on the information you provide I am guessing that the circuit breaker is overkill as the circuit probably isn't capable of delivering thousands of amps under a fault condition.